# Why did Heinz evidently know so little about Georgia?

Tags: georgian-language, lasha-bugadze, the-literature-express

When Zaza is informed that he was selected to join The Literature Express in Lisbon, he wrote to the trip organizer, Heinz. Heinz wrote back with a letter that began, "Dear Mr. or Mrs. Zaza..." The narrator noted that Heinz evidently didn't know who he was writing to and informed him that Zaza is exclusively a male name.

Why did Heinz not know that, given that he was tasked with organizing a trip for Georgian writers?